[Layout children]: No route named "/users/[id]" exists in nested children: ["index", "users/[id]"] Expo Router
I am learning and newbie Expo Router and trying to implement the Tabs but i am getting following error.
Project Directory
app/
  (tabs)/
     users/
       [id].jsx
  _layout.jsx
  index.jsx
index.jsx

What is the solution of this error. ?
_layout under (tabs)
import React from "react"
import {Tabs} from "expo-router"
    
    const TabLayout = ({params}) => {
       return (
          <Tabs>
             <Tabs.Screen name='/index' options={{headerTitle: "Home"}} />
             <Tabs.Screen name='/users/[id]' options={{headerTitle: "Users"}} />
          </Tabs>
       )
    }
    
    export default TabLayout

I have tried updating codebase but i doesn't work. I should not get error.
Thanks

I have a found a solution by removing / in _layout.jsx from name worked for me.
Updated _layout.jsx
import React from "react"
import {Tabs} from "expo-router"
const TabLayout = ({params}) => {
   return (
      <Tabs>
         <Tabs.Screen name='index' options={{headerTitle: "Home"}} />
         <Tabs.Screen name='users/[id]' options={{headerTitle: "Users"}} />
      </Tabs>
   )
}

export default TabLayout

Hope it will help someone.
Thank you
